# NoReverseMatch but I pass all the parameters

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am building a function to incremente a model when a user click on a link, but even thought I pass all the parameters, I still cannot resolve this issue.

> Reverse for 'karma' with keyword arguments '{'token': '503e9db5-daf3-4d3a-83fd-0d28bf923225', 'karma_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['workspace/(?P[^/]+)/karma/(?P[^/]+)$']

Here is my views :

```
def karmaget(request, karma_id, token):
    karma = karma.objects.get(pk=karma_id)
    karma.point = +1
    karma.author = request.user
    karma.save()
    return redirect('workspace-detail', token=token)
```

Here is my url :

```
path('<str:token>/karma/<karma_id>', views.karmaget, name='karma'),
```

And my template :

```
<a href="{% url 'karma' token=token karma_id=karma.pk %}">
```

Comment: Can you show view from which template with `<a href="{% url 'karma' token=token karma_id=karma.pk %}">` rendering?

Comment: Seems `karma.id` is empty.

Comment: @nima but I have created one karma model so it should not be empty right ?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner what do you mean, my view is on the top of my post

Comment: I mean in which view this template which you show rendering? Can you add it?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner the view ? I am not going to display my full view, the only problem occur with my function view.

If you are talking about the template It's just a blank html with the link, sorry but your request it's not very clear

Answer (score 1):

Should be karma.points +=1 to increment